# Swagger retorna erro ao subir a API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

Estou pegando esse erro:

> Fetch errorundefined https://localhost:44358/swagger/v2/swagger.json

Quando eu tinha apenas uma controller, o swagger subia normalmente e eu conseguia fazer os meus testes e etc. Agora, ao acrescentar a segunda controller, começou a dar esse erro. As minhas controllers tem os mesmos nomes dos métodos, apenas apontando para suas respectivas Model. Por exemplo, para deletar uso `Delete`, para pegar dados apenas, tenho `Get()` e `Get(int id)`, em todas as controllers esses são os nome. Achei que pudesse ser isso. Todas as controllers são decoradas com `Route("api/[controller]")`. Meu `startup` no método `ConfigureService` tenho isso

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiInfo
    {
        Title = "Minha API",
        Version = "v2",
        Description = "Teste de admissão",
    });
});
```

E ainda no `Startup` no método Configure tenho

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{            
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("v2/swagger.json", "Minha API V2");
        });
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
           name: "defaut",
           pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(options => options
        .SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "Minha API"));
}
```

E no meu LaunchSettings eu tenho:

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MinhaApi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
}
```

Realmente não sei o que fazer para resolver esse erro

As controllers(Desenvolvedor)

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DesenvolvedorController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MeuContext _context;
        private DesenvolvedorService _service;

        //Paginação
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string filter, int pageindex = 1, string sort = "Nome")
        {
            var resultado = _context.Desenvolvedores.AsNoTracking()
                                        .AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
            {
                resultado = resultado.Where(p => p.Nome.Contains(filter));
            }
            var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(resultado, 5, pageindex, sort, "Nome");
            model.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary { { "filter", filter } };
            return View(model);
        }

        public DesenvolvedorController(DesenvolvedorService service, MeuContext  context)
        {
            _service = service;
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Desenvolvedor> Get()
        {
            return _service.Get();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var desenvolvedor = _service.Get(id);
            if (desenvolvedor != null)
                return new ObjectResult(desenvolvedor);
            else
                return NotFound();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] Desenvolvedor desenvolvedor)
        {
            _service.Post(desenvolvedor);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public Resultado Put([FromBody] Desenvolvedor desenvolvedor)
        {
            return _service.Put(desenvolvedor);
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public Resultado Delete(int id)
        {
            return _service.Delete(id);
        }
```

E a controller Projeto

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProjetoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly MeuContext _context;
        private ProjetoService _service;

        //Paginação
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string filter, int pageindex = 1, string sort = "Nome")
        {
            var resultado = _context.Desenvolvedores.AsNoTracking()
                                        .AsQueryable();

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
            {
                resultado = resultado.Where(p => p.Nome.Contains(filter));
            }
            var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(resultado, 5, pageindex, sort, "Nome");
            model.RouteValue = new RouteValueDictionary { { "filter", filter } };
            return View(model);
        }
        public ProjetoController(ProjetoService service, MeuContext context)
        {
            _service = service;
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Projeto> Get()
        {
            return _service.Get();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var projeto = _service.Get(id);
            if (projeto != null)
                return new ObjectResult(projeto);
            else
                return NotFound();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] Projeto projeto)
        {
            _service.Post(projeto);
        }

        [HttpPut]
        public Resultado Put([FromBody] Projeto projeto)
        {
            return _service.Put(projeto);
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        public Resultado Delete(int id)
        {
            return _service.Delete(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: pode postar também as duas controllers?

Comment: @novic, postei as duas controllers, conforme me pediu.

Comment: não monstrou nada ainda

Comment: O problema está na paginação. Quando comentei em ambas as controllers, aí o swagger funcionou.

Comment: Fiz isso e rolou: `[HttpGet("paginacao/{id}")]`

Comment: @novic, houve um erro aqui e não subiu a edição. Achei que tinha subido, mas não subiu. Desculpa aí.

Answer (score 0):

No endpoint:

```
//Paginação
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string filter, int pageindex = 1, string sort = "Nome")
```

Você precisa seguir as regras da convenção de API e utilizar: `HttpMethodAttribute`

No exemplo a seguir o `[HttpGet]`

```
//Paginação
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery]string filter, [FromQuery]int pageindex = 1, [FromQuery]string sort = "Nome"){}
```

Será necessário onfigurar o metodo Get para nao dar conflito com outros métodos Get ja existente. Uma alternativa é criar uma nova **api/controller** para realizar essa pesquisa.